# Why is "Self Time" so high in an effectively empty function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, v8

I have a computationally heavy function which is called many times in a loop:

```js
function func() { // Some fluff
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    i *= 10
    i /= 10
  }
}

function run() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    func()
  }
}

run()
```

When I profile this script using Chrome's DevTools, I get this:

[image]

`run` has a self time of 887ms out of the total time of 1015ms even though the only thing it does is repeatedly call `func`.

I would expect `func` to have the majority of self time since it's a leaf function.

Why is this?

Comment: It's either a bug or the function was automatically inlined after some time when it became "hot".

Comment: Doesn't this just show that performing 100000 function calls are more expensive than a 1000 iterations of two simple arithmetic operations -- which makes sense?

Comment: @wOxxOm I'd go with the latter. This is not very realistic code. Trying to draw conclusions from it doesn't really make sense - the code might have been optimised on the fly. Other code might work differently. It's important to profile real code.

Comment: @VLAZ This happened with my real code, I was just trying to produce a minimal reproducible example since copying my entire project into a SO question isn't ideal.

Comment: @Phillip Don't forget that the 1000 iterations of two simple arithmetic operations are themselves called 100000 times: 100000000 iterations in reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> the function was automatically inlined after some time when it became "hot".

Correct. As soon as `run` is optimized, the optimizer decides to inline `func` into it. After that, as far as the profiler is concerned, all the time is spent in `run`.
(To verify this, run the snippet in `d8` or `node` with `--trace-turbo-inlining`.)
Side note: getting to optimized code for `run` takes a bit longer than usual in this case, because the function never returns to get called again (which is the best time to switch to optimized code). The system waits a bit for that to happen, and when it doesn't happen, `run` is eventually "on-stack replaced". This is a typical pattern that occurs frequently in small tests and benchmarks, and rarely in real-world code.

> Doesn't this just show that performing 100000 function calls are more expensive than a 1000 iterations of two simple arithmetic operations -- which makes sense?

No, it doesn't show that; that's just one particular way how one could be misled by this microbenchmark.

Personally, I'm mildly disappointed to see (with `--print-opt-code`) that the compiler didn't realize that `i *= 10; i /= 10;` is a no-op and could be dropped entirely. That would have been another great way to be misled here. Oh well, there's probably some reason why it's harder than it looks for the compiler to figure out that that transformation would be both applicable and safe...